# Find a homogeneous Cauchy-Euler equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a homogeneous Cauchy-Euler equation whose general solution is given by $$y(x) = \frac{c_1 \cos(2 \ln x) + c_2 \sin(2 \ln x))}{x^3} ,\quad x > 0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y(x) = \frac{c_1 \cos(2 \ln x) + c_2 \sin(2 \ln x))}{x^3} ,\quad x > 0.$$
Substitute $x=e^t$:
$$e^{3t}y(t) = {c_1 \cos(2t) + c_2 \sin(2t)}$$
$$z(t)=e^{3t}y(t)  = {c_1 \cos(2t) + c_2 \sin(2t)}$$
You can deduce from this the characteristic equation :
$$(r-2i)(r+2i)=r^2+4=0$$
It's easy to deduce the DE:
$$z''(t)+4z(t)=0$$
$$(ye^{3t})''+4ye^{3t}=0$$
$$y''(t)+6y'(t)+13y(t)=0$$
Back to $x$ variable $(t=\ln x)$:
$$x^2y''(x)+7xy'(x)+13y(x)=0$$

---

$$y(x) = \frac{c_1 \cos(2 \ln x) + c_2 \sin(2 \ln x))}{x^3} ,\quad x > 0.$$
It's a solution to a Cauchy–Euler's differential equation where $x^m$ is a solution with $m=-3 \pm 2i$.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that for a given Cauchy-Euler equation $$ax^2y''(x) + bxy'(x) + cy(x) = 0$$we look for solutions of the form $y(x) = x^p$. Plugging that we have $$ax^2p(p-1)x^{p-2} + bxpx^{p-1} + cx^p = 0,$$so we impose $ap(p-1) + bp+c=0$. This means $ap^2+ (b-a)p+c = 0$. If you have a complex solution $\alpha+{\rm i}\beta$, then the solution would be $$y(x) = x^{\alpha+{\rm i}\beta} = x^\alpha x^{{\rm i}\beta} = x^\alpha {\rm e}^{\ln x^{{\rm i}\beta}} = x^\alpha {\rm e}^{\beta{\rm i}\ln x} = x^\alpha(\cos(\beta \ln x)+{\rm i}\sin(\beta \ln x)).$$Now, real and imaginary parts of a complex solution to a real equation are solutions themselves, so that would lead to $$y(x) = c_1x^\alpha \cos(\beta \ln x) + c_2 x^\alpha \sin(\beta \ln x).$$That understood, we'll reverse engineer the characteristic equation. You want $\alpha = -3$ and $\beta = 2$. Meaning that the characteristic equation should be $$0 = (p-(-3+2{\rm i}))(p-(-3-2{\rm i})) = (p+3-2{\rm i})(p+3+2{\rm i}) = (p+3)^3 + 1 = p^2+6p+13.$$Now compare $p^2 + 6p+13 = 0$ with $ap^2+(b-a)p+c=0$. Choose $a=1$, so that $b=7$, while obviously $c=13$. The equation you're looking for is $$x^2y''(x) + 7xy'(x) + 13y(x) = 0.$$Check.